# PHP text over image foreach

Tags: php

I'm running a foreach that gets info and then the value is used to set the high of an image(bar).

Im trying to add the value in text above the bar as well but keeps coming up side by side next to the bar. Any ideas? keep in mind this is done within a foreach so there are 10 values with 10 images.

code:

```
<?php echo "$textvalue"; ?>

<img src="images/bar_offpeak.jpg" alt="" width="19" height="<?php echo "$height" ?>%" title="<?php echo "$textvalue" ?>GB" />
```

Comment: @Mr.Alien That's a pretty common syntax when using PHP as a templating language.

Comment: @ceejayoz only `?` is sufficient? never came across such

Comment: @Mr.Alien It seems the OP just had some problems formatting the code: `excuse the brackets , didnt wanna show in this post...`

Comment: @jeroen I guess stack keeps the markup as it is, just don't show on the front unless it is highlighted, anyways its ok :) but I don't know who deleted my comment without commenting any reason for doing so

Comment: @Mr.Alien I think only a moderator can do that. The reason is probably to avoid confusion as it did not really apply any more to the edited version of the question.

Comment: @jeroen Yea, but moderators should comment out the reason for deleting, it's good for users to avoid more confusion :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `<br />` element after the text. By default, simple text and images float.

This is what you want to do:

```
<?php echo "$textvalue"; ?><br />

<img src="images/bar_offpeak.jpg" alt="" width="19" height="<?php echo "$height" ?>%" title="<?php echo "$textvalue" ?>GB" />
```

Later edit:

My mistake sir, I seem to have forgotten about that part. In this case, one solution is to display each image and text in a div element. This way, you can float the div's any way you want (i.e. display any number of row/columns you want).

So, one item would like so:

```
<div style="float:left;">
    <?php echo "$textvalue"; ?><br />

    <img src="images/bar_offpeak.jpg" alt="" width="19" height="<?php echo "$height" ?>%" title="<?php echo "$textvalue" ?>GB" />
</div>
```

And whenever you want to create a new row, just insert a div like this:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

This should be a good idea to get you on the right path. But, as Jeroen suggested, you should use a more layout-oriented approach.

Hope this helps. Have a great day:

Comment: Images don't float, they are simply inline, so float is a wrong word :)

Comment: haha tried that , doesnt work , remember its foreach so its adds all the images on top of each other and not side by side when adding </br>.
so images must be side by side with text value on top of them

Comment: Thank you for the correction @Mr.Alien. I'll be careful not to mix terms next time :)

Answer (score 1):

I would not use a `<br>` tag to manipulate the layout. I would recommend putting the text in an element (a `span`, `figcaption`, etc.) and use css to control the layout.

Assuming html5:

```
<figure>
  <figcaption><?php echo $textvalue; ?></figcaption>
  <img src="images/bar_offpeak.jpg" alt="" width="19" height="<?php echo $height ?>%" title="<?php echo $textvalue ?>GB" />
</figure>
```

And in the css (just an example):

```
figcaption {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Nice one! Thank you for posting. This should be considered as the correct answer :)